# How to query data inserting substring - MYSQL/JPQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpql

I'm writing the below method on a Java project with Hibernate connecting to the database, and want to know how can I write a query to find a register with just the corrensponding substring. I tried using 'concat' but it didn't work

```
public List<UnidadeDeSaude> pesquisar(String nome) {
        TypedQuery<UnidadeDeSaude> query = manager.createQuery("from UnidadeDeSaude where nomeDoEstabelecimento concat('%',:nomeDoEstabelecimento,'%')", UnidadeDeSaude.class);
        query.setParameter("nomeDoEstabelecimento", nome + '%');
        
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [LIKE clause](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-like-queries)

```
from UnidadeDeSaude where nomeDoEstabelecimento like concat('%',:nomeDoEstabelecimento,'%')", UnidadeDeSaude.class);
```

And skip the `+ '%'` from `setParameter`